# New row based on other's row past value to current value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, shift

I'm trying to create a new column called `move` in `df` that gives the value of `1` if the value in `x is higher` than its previous value and a `0` if the `value is lower`, so the first value in `move` should be a `NaN`.

```
d = {'x': [1, 0, 2, 5, 4]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```

The column should look like this:

```
df['move'] = pandas.Series([NaN, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare using `shift` with a slice of the column using `iloc` and cast the boolean series to numeric dtype using `astype`:

```
In [82]:
df['move'] = (df['x'].iloc[1:] > df['x'].iloc[1:].shift()).astype(int)
df

Out[82]:
   x  move
0  1   NaN
1  0   0.0
2  2   1.0
3  5   1.0
4  4   0.0
```

Note that the presence of `NaN` forces the dtype to be `float` here

Answer (score 0):

I think you need compare with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values in column `x` and last you can change first value to `NaN` (if necessary):

```
df['move'] = (df.x > df.x.shift()).astype(int)
df.ix[0, 'move'] = np.nan
print (df)
   x  move
0  1   NaN
1  0   0.0
2  2   1.0
3  5   1.0
4  4   0.0
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=50k`:

```
In [82]: %timeit (edch(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.99 ms per loop

In [83]: %timeit (jez(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
d = {'x': [1, 0, 2, 5, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()

def jez(df):
    df['move'] = (df.x > df.x.shift()).astype(int)
    df.ix[0, 'move'] = np.nan
    return df

def edch(df):
    df['move'] = (df['x'].iloc[1:] > df['x'].iloc[1:].shift()).astype(int)
    return df

print (jez(df))
print (edch(df1))
```